# KVM-Guests can't get past bridge - no internet connection

Tags: linux, networking, debian, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I'm running a backported KVM on a Debian Squeeze. ATM the KVM-Guest can't connect to the internet through the bridge I have set up. The guests can reach each other, the host but nothing outside. I can neither ping, nslookup or do anything to a remote address. The guest are configured to have a static IP. When I didn;t have the bridge but a virtual bridge (the KVM-default) the guest could connect fine. After setting up the bridge things broke, so I think the problem lies there.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo br0
iface lo inet loopback

# Bonding Interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 10.XXX.XXX.84
netmask 255.255.255.192
network 10.XXX.XXX.64
gateway 10.XXX.XXX.65
slaves eth0 eth1
bond_mode active-backup
bond_miimon 100
bond_downdelay 200
bond_updelay 200

iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
    address 172.xxx.xxx.65
    broadcast 172.xxx.xxx.127
    netmask 255.255.255.192
    gateway 172.xxx.xxx.65
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, silly me - as it turns out the problem was that the interface and the gateway had the same IP.

Answer (score 2):

1.) You're putting eth0 and eth1 into a bonding group and you're bridging them into br0 - you can't do both.  Have you tried putting bond0 in instead?

2.) Also - why do you have STP on?  Unless you're trying to bridge external segments together in a redundant topology or are you trying to connect a bonded interface to your VM's?  Turn it off unless you need it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried putting bond0, but with no luck. But I removed the stp, don't know why it was there ^^

Comment: Confirm that the interfaces are actually up and operational (i.e. receiving / sending frames) - both from ifconfig and with tcpdump.  I've seen a number of cases where Debian/Ubuntu will correctly configure some of these bridged interfaces but not actually bring them up.

Comment: In ifconfig I see the interfaces up and I also see traffic with tcpdump (e.g ssh traffic). Plus, it's a remote server, so if it wasn't up I couldn't connect to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

Make sure the host's iptables aren't getting in the way of the guests!