# Ubuntu KVM - Can't access network through bridge from guests, no DHCP, no ping

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS graphical (so has Network-Manager et al installed). I think I've got KVM and QEMU installed correctly. When trying to set up a Debian VM from the netinstall ISO, it fails to get an address from DHCP. I need to be able to access the VM from outside my laptop so I can't use NAT.

I've tried following instructions from:
[How do I configure bridged networking for VMs](https://serverfault.com/questions/585020/how-do-i-configure-bridged-networking-for-vms)
[KVM-Guests can't get past bridge - no internet connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/394578/kvm-guests-cant-get-past-bridge-no-internet-connection)
[KVM guest is unable to access the internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/667304/kvm-guest-is-unable-to-access-the-internet)
But still no luck.

The laptop is a Dell XPS 13 and has no onboard NIC. Instead, I have a TP-Link USB3.0 Gigabit ethernet adapter attached, which according to the spec page is an RTL8153 chipset. Ethernet is working fine on the host. Wifi is disabled.

I have tried configuring the bridge through the Virt-Manager GUI, through brctl and defining it in /etc/network/interfaces. As best I can tell, the bridge is up and functional, but trying to ping outside the VM results in failure. At one point I was able to ping the host laptop's IP, but no further than that (I can't remember what I did to cause this and it's no longer the case, pinging anything on the same subnet results in the packets disappearing, pinging Google results in `Network is unreachable`. I have stopped the ufw service and additionally flushed the iptables rules, each to no avail. I have Docker on the same machine, but I don't know if that makes any difference.

**Host machine:**

*ifconfig:*

```
root@DB0277:~# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:6e:0e:06:29:c1  
          inet addr:10.11.x.44  Bcast:10.11.x.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d66e:eff:fe06:29c1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:667579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:351430 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:907499432 (907.4 MB)  TX bytes:21171832 (21.1 MB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:54:45:ff:85  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enxd46e0e0629c1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:6e:0e:06:29:c1  
          inet addr:10.11.x.44  Bcast:10.11.x.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:672999 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:354674 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:909372154 (909.3 MB)  TX bytes:21561645 (21.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:112607 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:112607 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:143555055 (143.5 MB)  TX bytes:143555055 (143.5 MB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:6d:02:e7  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2860 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:963296 (963.2 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

*brctl:*

```
root@DB0277:~# brctl show
bridge name bridge id           STP enabled interfaces
br0         8000.d46e0e0629c1   no          enxd46e0e0629c1
docker0     8000.02425445ff85   no      
virbr0      8000.fe54006d02e7   yes         vnet0
```

*/etc/network/interfaces:*

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
   bridge_ports enxd46e0e0629c1
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0.0
```

*iptables:*

```
root@DB0277:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

*routes:*

```
root@DB0277:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.11.x.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
10.11.x.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
10.11.y.21    10.11.x.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enxd46e0e0629c1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

The guest OS is unmodified Debian 9.0 netinstall.

Posting this in ServerFault because I've successfully set up two KVM hosts without any of these problems. What have I overlooked?

Comment: Bridge is the same as unmanaged switch. Why do you use different IP networks on bridge interface and on connected to the bridge `enxd46e0e0629c1` interface? Usually only one IP address is assigned on bridge interface or physical interface.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? I have the exact same issues. Testing from the VM that doesn't get an IP with ```tcpdump -vv``` I see that ARP  traffic from the host network does get through but no TCP and UDP packages are having checksum errors

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you solved this?

Comment: Afraid I never solved this issue. I think I set this up on a desktop with dual PCI NICs instead of the XPS. Never got the bottom of why it happened with the USB NIC.